How to remove files which confirm to a certain number pattern
How to remove files which confirm to a certain number pattern
I remove like this right now in MacOS,
rm */sections.json.* */sections.json0* */sections.json1* all the way till 9


Please [edit] your question and i) tell us your operating system, ii) tell us the shell you are using (bash, zsh, dash, sh, something else?), iii) explain what number pattern you are looking for. Show us some examples of files that should be kept, and files that should be deleted, and explain how we can differentiate between the two. Should sections.json10 be removed, for instance or do we stop at 9? Can you have sections.json-1?

Its MacOS machine

OK, but please read the entire comment, and EDIT the information, the answers to all the questions into your question.

Assuming you want to delete the sections.json.<anything> and the sections.json<a-number-between-0-and-9> files¹, With the zsh shell:
rm -- */sections.json(.*|[0-9])

With the bash shell (where with the extglob option, it implements a subset of ksh's extended operators):
shopt -s failglob extglob
rm -- */sections.json@(.*|[0123456789])

(avoid [0-9] in bash which on many systems matches hundreds of characters beside 0123456789).
If the range was wider than single digits 0 to 9, you'd need zsh's <0-123> decimal number matching operator:
rm -- */sections.json(.*|<0-123>)

Note that that <0-123> also matches on 005 or 0000118 which also are decimal integer representations of numbers in between 1 and 123.
To exclude those with a leading 0, you'd use the ~ (except) extendedglob operator like (0|(<1-123>~0*)) in place of <0-123>, that is:  *either 0 or any decimal integer representation of a number inbetween 1 and 123 except those that start with 0).
To match the same without that dedicated operator, with bash -O extglob -O failglob, you'd need to construct a complex pattern such as:
rm -- */sections.json@(.*|*(0)@(@(?([0123456789])|1[01])[0123456789]|12[0123]))

Or:
rm -- */sections.json@(.*|@(@(?([123456789])|1[01])[0123456789]|12[0123]))

To exclude the ones with leading 0s.
Another (brute-force) approach in bash would be to construct a @(.*|0|1|2|...|122|123) pattern, which you could do with:
alternatives=( '.*' {0..123} )
IFS='|'
pattern="@(${alternatives[*]})"
IFS=
rm -- */sections.json$pattern # note $pattern must remain unquoted

(both {x..y} and array=(...) are actually initially from zsh).
It's easier in zsh where there's a proper joining operator and even one dedicated to joining using glob operators; you can also use an anonymous function for the array to be its arguments:
() { rm -- */sections.json(.*|${(~j[|])argv}); } {0..123}

Now, if you want to allow anything after the numbers, you can't just append *, as sections.json<1-123>* would match on sections.json124 where <1-123> would match on 12 and * on 4, you'd need to append (|[^0-9]*) in zsh (or ^[0-9]* with extendedglob) or ?([^0123456789]*) or !([0123456789]*) with bash -O extglob -O failglob to make sure the number stays within the 1..123 range.

¹ Note that your */sections.json1* for instance would match on dir/sections.json123.tar.gz so you won't restrict the range to numbers from 0 to 9.

Taking a closer look at the question, they have *s after the digits, so [.0-9]* suffices and is more portable.

You can also use braces in bash like
rm */sections.json{0..9}*


Note that bash copied that operator from zsh (or probably from ksh93 which copied it from zsh), but it's not a glob operator, it will first expand to rm */sections.json0* */sections.json1*... */sections.json9 and then expand 10 different globs, so is less efficient than rm */sections.json[0123456789]* (which can be shortened to rm */sections.json[0-9]* in zsh) which expands only one glob.

POSIX-portable solution:
rm -- */sections.json[.0-9]*


Note that what [.0-9] matches is unspecified outside the POSIX/C locale. With zsh that's equivalent to [.0123456789] but in bash, that often matches hundreds of other characters.

Beware that except in zsh (or in bash if you enable the failglob option), if the pattern doesn't match any file, it will delete the file called */sections.json[.0-9]* if present.
